# Sveltekit: Wait for resolve in +layout.ts before load() in +page.ts

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I need a global value in my `+page.ts` `load()` function which is being fetched by `+layout.ts`. The problem is that I cannot get `+page.ts`'s `load()` to wait.
I tried passing it as `data` but cannot access it in the `+page.ts` `load()`. I also tried writing it into a writable store and accessing it but generally the page `load()` fires before the layout fetch resolves.
How can I solve this?

```js
// +layout.ts
export const load = ()=>{
  const globalData = await getGlobalData();
  store.setData(globalData);
  return {globalData}
}

// +page.ts
export const load = ({data})=>{
  // data returns null

  const globalData = store.getData();
  // fires before globalData is available
  const stuff = getPageData(globalData);

  return {stuff}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use `parent`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-parent-data) to load the data of any parent layout/s.

```js
export const load = async ({ parent }) => {
    const { globalData } = await parent();
    ...
};
```

Do not try to set global objects, it will cause chaos with concurrent requests.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that parent was for the parent in the route (and also wasn't expecting a function). This works sweet